# Is this method of showing that $\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} \rightarrow 0$ correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

Given
$$
a_n = \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}
$$
I want to show that
$$
a_n \rightarrow 0
$$
My solution proceeds as follows.
\begin{align}
\left\lvert \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 0 \right\rvert &< \epsilon \\
\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} &< \epsilon
\end{align}
since
\begin{align}
\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} &< \frac{2n^2}{n^3} \\
&= \frac{2}{n}
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
\frac{2}{n} < \epsilon \implies n > \frac{2}{\epsilon}
\end{align}
Therefore, let $N = \frac{2}{\epsilon}$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall n > N$,
\begin{align}
\left\lvert \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 0 \right\rvert < \frac{2}{n} < \frac{2}{N} = \epsilon
\end{align}
I am relying on the fact that since $\lvert a_n - 0 \rvert$ is upper-bounded by $\frac{2}{n}$, then the $N$ that I find for $\frac{2}{n}$ will be greater than the $N$ that I find for $\lvert a_n - 0 \rvert$.

Is all of this correct? If so, is there a name for this kind of method/reasoning?

Comment: I agree  with your analysis, and the adjective that I apply to this type of reasoning is *elegant*.

Comment: Also, see when you start with $\dfrac{2n^2}{n^3+3}< \epsilon $ and then show that $\dfrac{2n^2}{n^3+3}<\dfrac{2}{n}$, you're still required to show that $\dfrac{2}{n}< \epsilon $, that's because you fixed an $\epsilon$ too soon. Instead, start by showing that $\dfrac{2n^2}{n^3+3}<\dfrac{2}{n}$ first then show that for any $\epsilon$, however small, you can find a sufficiently large $N$ such that $\dfrac{2}{n} < \epsilon $ for each $n≥N$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two points:

1. You set $N:=\tfrac{2}{\varepsilon}$. But what is $\varepsilon$? Also $N$ need not be an integer. That's fine, but the symbol $N$ does suggest an integer value.
2. Next you *'fix $\varepsilon$ such that $\forall n>N$...'*.
   But to prove that the limit equals $0$, you want to show that $$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists N)\left(n>N\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \left|\tfrac{2n^2}{n^3+3}-0\right|<\varepsilon\right).$$

So instead, you want to start off from something like *'Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given...'*, and then give an appropriate value of $N$, and show that the inequality does indeed hold.

Your first few steps are a good way to determine such an $N$ given some $\varepsilon>0$. You can follow these steps in reverse to show that given $\varepsilon>0$, the desired inequality holds for all $n>N$ for the $N$ that you found.

---

For example, my answer to the question

> Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}=0$.

would simply be:

> Given any $\varepsilon>0$, for all $n>\frac{2}{\varepsilon}$ we have
> \begin{align}
> \left\lvert \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3} - 0 \right\rvert <\left\lvert\frac{2n^2}{n^3}\right\rvert=\frac{2}{n}<\epsilon.
> \end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You are right. My wording was imprecise because I wrote this up quickly. Beyond this, given any sequence $a_n$ and limit $a$, is it usually possible to find an upper-bound for $\lvert a_n - a \rvert$ and then solve for $n$ to determine $N$, and finally work backwards? Basically, can my approach be generalized or does it only apply to this case?

Comment: Yes. Your argument implicitly uses the fact that $a_n\geq0$ for all $n$. So you've bounded the sequence from both sides by two sequences that both tend to $0$. This is an instance of the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).